# Sql Lite Primary key for Application

Tags: android, sqlite, primary-key

Hi can anyone one suggest me a primary key(type:long) implementation which is for each installed android application. 
This will help me much.
Checked below link. But it will return type string.
[Identifying-app-installations](http://android-developers.blogspot.co.uk/2011/03/identifying-app-installations.html)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can i get the reason for downvoting?

Comment: maybe you got downvote because there's no way to generate a random UUID in type:long. if you want, you can generate your UUID contain only number using random() method

Comment: Nothing is impossible. 
I did by converting string to char and char to long. Still it is little big.But if anyone is having good solution then it would help me a lot :).

Comment: when you use UUID to generate random UUID, it will generate like this one `123e4567-e89b-12d3-a456-426655440000`. there's no way you put not number element into long type

Comment: Thanks for the info.
i did like taking android application package name like com.package.name as "String" then do String->Char->long you will get unique ID for each application.

Comment: What is the problem and what does sqlite primary key have to do with it?

Comment: I have to store each individual application details in sql lite. Like - Name,InstalledOn,DataUsage,TotalSize.here i am updating data usage for each hour/day etc. for that i need a primary key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`long` is a 64-bit type, but there are more than 2<sup>64</sup> possible application IDs. This is not possible.

Just use the string as primary key.

Comment: Just referred this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20094992/greendao-string-primary-keys-how-to-use Thanks CL.